# What is the relevance of "Hands Across America" in Us?

Tags: plot-explanation, us

What is the significance of Hands Across America in the movie [*Us*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6857112/)?

Why do the tethered go form that long line?

(The actual event happened in the 80s and was a charity thing)
Is there some something metaphorical that Peele was trying to imply?